# Implicit Function Theorem

Tags: analysis

Lets $F(x, y, z):\mathbb{R}^{3}\to\mathbb{R}^{1}$, and lets $F_y\neq 0$ and $F_z\neq 0$ in some neighborhood $V$ of $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$.

Am I right that:
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$$
and hence
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=0$$
in $V\ni(x_0, y_0, z_0).$

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but for rather silly reasons: when you consider the partial derivative with respect to $x$, you are taking $y$ and $z$ to be *fixed*. Being fixed, they are constant relative to a change in $x$, hence 
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = 0.$$
That is, the values of $y$ and of $z$ *do not depend on $x$*, so their partial derivatives are zero. The fact that $F_y$ and $F_z$ are nonzero is irrelevant.